# How to get the timestamp from a Firebase database?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have the following method:

```
public async void generateTimeStampAsync()
{
    FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("MY Db project ID");
    CollectionReference collection = db.Collection("users");
    Query query = collection.WhereLessThan("Born", 1900);
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
}
```

How would I use this or a similar method to be able to get a server timestamp from the database? Something similar to the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in JavaScript. If you could provide any methods that is able to simply return the timestamp of the server to me, that would be great.

Comment: Please, **avoid** `async void` methods whenever possible.

Comment: I usually do, this is just for test purposes so that i don't need to return anything

Comment: If you don't need to return anything, use `async Task`.